# number date to word date

Tags: java, netbeans

need help, how to convert this in java? 09-09-2012 = September 9, 2012?
our instructor give it as an assignment.. Month, day, and year and inputted using separately

thnx in advance

```
package exam4;
```

`import java.text.ParseException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;`

`public class Exam4 {`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        String inMonth=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Month");
            int intMonth = Integer.parseInt(inMonth);

        String inDay=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Day");
            int intDay = Integer.parseInt(inDay);

        String inYear=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Year");
            int intYear = Integer.parseInt(inYear);

        getDate(intMonth, intDay, intYear);


}

static void getDate(int intMonth, int intDay, int intYear){

    if((intMonth==2)&&(intDay<=29)&&(intYear<=9999)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "February 29, 2012");
        genDate(intMonth,intDay,intYear);
    }         

        else if (((intMonth<12)&&(intDay<31)&&(intYear<9999))&&((intMonth==2)&&(intDay<=29)&&(intYear<=9999))){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Regular date");

        }

        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "atik na date");
        }
}

static void genDate(int intMonth, int intDay, int intYear){

        String fMonth = Integer.toString(intMonth);
        String fDay = Integer.toString(intDay);
        String fYear = Integer.toString(intYear);

        String DateTime=fMonth+fDay+fYear;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
    Date myDate = null;

        try {
            myDate = dateFormat.parse(DateTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          }

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
    String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,finalDate);

}
```

}

when i inputted the 02 02 2012, it gives me weird date... try to enter 02 29 2012.. and it gives december 13, 0013.. i dnt knw why =(

Comment: try this code sir michael.. try to enter 02 29 2012

Comment: Please don't use txt-speak when asking questions.  Proper English, with punctuation, is preferred here. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: sorry sir Jim and thanks for the reminder =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the string to date and then convert back to String as below:

```
     DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
     Date date = format1.parse("09-09-2012");
     DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
     String dateString = format2.format(date);
     System.out.println(dateString); //<- prints September 09, 2012
```

Comment: i tried but it gives me weird dates... try to enter 02,29,2012. and it gives a December 31, 0013

Comment: @renhangad You need to enter `02-29-2012`. With that, it prints `February 29, 2012`. I already made some corrections in the answer. Hope you are referring the updated format. It's working code.

Comment: @renhangad Did it work for you? If you wish to enter `02 29 2012` as the date then use `MM dd yyyy` as the date format string in the first statement. **Please make sure the input is supplied in the declared format**.

Comment: yup its working code. i think the problem in then i parse the int > String.. when i enter "02" as String the i parse it to int it becomes 2, the parse again to String it becomes "2". sir yogen any idea how to parse int 2 = String "02"?

Comment: @renhangad Even if you enter `2 29 2012` (without 0), it should be working(its working for me). Please make sure you use the same format i.e. use the same date string as format. I mean if you are using space as separation then define format with space. If you are using `-` as separator, then define format using `-`.

Comment: =) thnx sir yogen.. i forgot the "-" thing.. thank you so much

Comment: @renhangad: If you think this was helpful, please don't forget to accept the answer.